# Is there a way of not only adding/removing a class to an HTML element but actually change the value within a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As for example: I wanna show random background colors by pressing a button. I greated variables which would result in a usual hex-code if I put the strings together... Only how can I write these random values into the CSS file? Is there any way?

I do not wanna change the class name, but what the class name contains as a style-value for background-color!

```
function changeColor() {
var content = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
var one = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
var two = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
var three = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
var four = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
var five = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
var six = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
```

Comment: Different question: why are you creating `one`, `two`, etc instead of just using a function `getRandomValue(array)` and calling that whenever necessary? As for writing them to file: if you're client side in the browser there are no files to write to, so what do you want to _do_? If you want to show random colors, just edit whatever class(es) you're using by rewriting CSSRules in the appropriate `document.stylesheets` entry?

Comment: How to modify css file with javascript?

`.insertRule` and `.cssRules`

Comment: Take a read through MDN on the web APIs for stylesheets https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change inline styles you can take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) page:

> Changing HTML Style
>   - To change the style of an HTML element, use this syntax:
>
> `document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style` The following
>   example changes the style of a `<p>` element:
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <html>
> <body>
>
> <p id="p2">Hello World!</p>
>
> <script>
> document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
> </script>
>
> <p>The paragraph above was changed by a script.</p>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>
 
     <h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>

     <button type="button" 
     onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
     Click Me!</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Or

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>
 
     <h1 id="id1" style="color: blue">My Heading 1</h1>

     <button type="button" 
     onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style = 'color: red'">
     Click Me!</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: For the record, inline click handlers are horrible. Use addEventListener https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 2):

This is what we have the style attribute for

```js
function change(){
  var content = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
  var one = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
  var two = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
  var three = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
  var four = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
  var five = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
  var six = content[Math.floor(Math.random()*content.length)];
  document.getElementById("element").style.backgroundColor = "#"+one+two+three+four+five+six
}
```

```html
<div id="element">
  see the background
</div>
<button onclick="change()">change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onClick` event on the button press to call the 
`changeColor()` function.

```
<Button
       onClick={event => {
       event.preventDefault();
       this.changeColor();
    }}
>
```